# Mathematically prove whether it's possible to survive indefinitely in an unbounded tag game

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, game-theory, infinite-games

Suppose we have a tag game, with an unbounded (2D) map, where the player possesses a character in the map represented by it's (x,y) position, that can, at any frame, move 1 unit left, right, up or down, or stay still. Suppose there are other characters in the game (taggers) that possess the same moving capabilities, that spawn in a box left to the player, and the game can only end if the player gets tagged and dies (that is, if its position is equal to that of any of the taggers).

Now, if the goal is to survive as long as possible, I suppose it is possible by just moving right at each turn. The monsters will never catch me if I do this contantly, therefore allowing me to survive for as long as I like.

What I want, is to formalize this in mathematical terms somehow, but I literally don't know how to. Something that seems so clear, intuitive and logical, is also so hard to prove using that same logic, at least to me. I don't know where to start whether to prove if it is (not) possible to survive indefinitely, nor do I know to do the same to the particular case of bolting right at every instance.

If someone would like to have a crack at it, I would be very grateful.

Comment: You can approach this with [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). For the inductive step, you would assume that the runner can survive for $N$ turns with the monster somewhere to their left, and show that if they move right then they will survive the $N+1$ turn, and the monster will still be left of them, regardless of what the monster does.

Comment: @NickAlger I have thought of this, but I don't know how I could represent the many positions the player and the monsters can possess at every turn, depending on their choice of movement. I have thought of using distances rather than positions, since I could make intervals of the distance between player and monsters, but how would I deal with multiple monsters, for example?

Comment: No matter how many monsters are there, if the initial $x$ coordinate of every monster is less than that of a player, all you need to use is that $a < b \implies a+1 < b+ 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d(p-q)$ be the Manhattan distance between two position $p$ and $q$, that is:
$$d(p-q)=|p_x-q_x|+|p_y-q_y|$$
The goal of the tagger is to let $p(n) = q(n)$ after some $n$ moves a.k.a. $d(p(n)-q(n))=0$. WLOG, suppose that your position is $p$. Your strategy can be described as follows:
$$\begin{cases}
p_x(n+1)=p_x(n) +1 \text{, if } p_x(n) \geq q_x(n)\\
p_x(n+1)=p_x(n) -1 \text{, if } p_x(n) < q_x(n)
\end{cases}$$

To prove that this strategy allows you to survive indefinitely is to prove that $d(p(n),q(n))>0$ for all $n$ no matter what $q(n)$ is (assuming that $p(0) \neq q(0)$, ofc). This can be done by showing that $d(p(n)-q(n))$ doesn't decrease:
$$d(p(n+1),q(n+1))=|p_x(n+1)-q_x(n+1)|+|p_y(n+1)-q_y(n+1)|$$
If the opponent decided to take a vertical move, then $q_x(n+1) = q_x(n)$ and
$$
\begin{align}
d(p(n+1),q(n+1))&=|p_x(n)-q_x(n)| + 1 + |p_y(n+1)-q_y(n+1)|\\
&\geq |p_x(n)-q_x(n)| + 1 + |p_y(n)-q_y(n)|-1\\
&= |p_x(n)-q_x(n)| + |p_y(n)-q_y(n)|\\
&= d(p_x(n),q_x(n))
\end{align}
$$
If the opponent decided to take a horizontal move, then $q_y(n+1) = q_y(n)$ and $|p_x(n+1)-q_x(n+1)| \geq |p_x(n)-q_x(n)|$ hence
$$\begin{align}
d(p(n+1),q(n+1)) &\geq |p_x(n)-q_x(n)| + 1 + |p_y(n)-q_y(n)|\\
&= d(p(n),q(n))
\end{align}
\\$$